# Spring Boot - update data

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, backend

I have a little problem.
I try update in repository one column.

Repository

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Conversation conversation SET conversation.friend = ?1 WHERE conversation.id = ?2")
fun setConversationInfoById(friend: Boolean, id: UUID): List<Conversation>
```

Service

```
fun addDeleteFriend(conversation: Conversation) {
    val openedConversation = db.findByIdOrNull(conversation.id)

    if (openedConversation == null) db.save(conversation)
    else db.setConversationInfoById(openedConversation.friend, openedConversation.id)
}
```

Controler

```
@PostMapping("/friend", consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
        @ResponseBody
        fun friend(@RequestBody conversation: Conversation) = service.addDeleteFriend(conversation)
```

It's about the flag - boolean whos will change status column "friend".

When I'm starting BE the console shows me this error:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with
 name 'conversationController' defined in file [####]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name
 'conversationService' defined in file [####]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'conversationRepository' defined in com.###.backend.repository.ConversationRepository defined in 
@EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration:
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for 
public abstract java.util.List com.###.backend.repository.ConversationRepository.setConversationInfoById(boolean,java.util.UUID)!
 Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List 
com.##.backend.repository.ConversationRepository.setConversationInfoById(boolean,java.util.UUID)!
 No property 'setConversationInfoById' found for type 'Conversation'!; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract 
java.util.List com.###.backend.repository.ConversationRepository.setConversationInfoById(boolean,java.util.UUID)!
 No property 'setConversationInfoById' found for type 'Conversation'!
```

I tried all option, but I don't know what is the problem ..

Comment: Why your repository return a List?

Comment: Can you please share the Conversation class?

Answer (score 0):

query method changes Conversation data by id, which is one data.
So it will be return one Conversation object.

try to change List to Conversation.

or, I don't know well, but quertymethod naming convention is exist, so try to check out.